# How to transpose when the value is a txt an the new column is a number

Tags: r, transpose

I have the following table

```
id  mycol counter
1   a      1
1   b      2
2   c      1
2   c      2
2   e      3
```

And this is what I neee

```
ID 1  2  3
1  a  b  done
2  c  c  done
```

I try to use the dcast function

```
mydata<-dcast(mydata, id~mycol, counter, value = 'mycol')
```

but It's not working, any idea?

Comment: Why do you have `done` in column `3`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears from your question that you're trying to do something like a reshaping from long to wide format. Here's how you can use base R [`reshape()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/reshape.html) to do this:

```
mydata <- data.frame(id=c(1L,1L,2L,2L,2L),mycol=c('a','b','c','c','e'),counter=c(1L,2L,1L,2L,3L),stringsAsFactors=F);
reshape(mydata,dir='w',idvar='id',timevar='counter');
##   id mycol.1 mycol.2 mycol.3
## 1  1       a       b    <NA>
## 3  2       c       c       e
```

---

`reshape()` does not support such precise control over the resulting column names. You can fix them up yourself afterward. Assuming you saved the above result as `res`, you can do this:

```
colnames(res) <- sub(perl=T,'^mycol\\.','',colnames(res));
res;
##   id 1 2    3
## 1  1 a b <NA>
## 3  2 c c    e
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply but  where in the code are you referring to mycol?

Comment: Besides using `mycol` as the name of the middle column when defining the `mydata` object, I don't refer to `mycol` in the code. The `reshape()` function dynamically constructs the wide varying columns from the non-idvar non-timevar columns.

Comment: In fact what i am looking for is that the counter will become the column, in your example the column name are col.1...col.3

Comment: Should i turn my counter to a txt variable?

Comment: @user4797853 See edit. No, you don't have to turn `counter` into a character vector.

Comment: Sorry !one ore question. Why you wrote counter=c(1L,2L,1L,2L,3L) instead  of counter=c(1,2,1,2,3)

Comment: The `L` suffix on numeric literals specifies that the R interpreter should interpret those literals as integers, rather than doubles (which are the default). I actually generated the `mydata <- ...` assignment statement using a Perl script I've written that allows me to convert standard data.frame output to such assignment statements. I've written the script to guess the type of each column, preferring integer over double when possible. It's not really significant in most cases, and it's not significant for the `reshape()` transformation.

Comment: Thank you sir, much appreciated.